# Inertia.js ssr: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-8, laravel-mix, inertiajs

I am using Laravel 8 with Inertia.js version 0.5.4. Can anyone help solve this problem? The app works fine without the ssr. I think the problem is in the Webpack config file.

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

**package.json**

```
"@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
"@inertiajs/inertia-vue": "^0.8.0",
"laravel-mix": "^6.0",
"sass": "~1.32",
"sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
"vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.3.1",
"vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
"vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0",
"webpack": "^5.59.1",
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
"vuetify": "^2.5.5",
"vuetifyjs-mix-extension": "0.0.20",
"vuex": "^3.4.0",
"webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
```

**webpack.ssr.mix.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

mix
    .options({ manifest: false, processCssUrls: false })
    .js('resources/js/ssr.js', 'public/js')
    .vue({
        version: 2, options: { optimizeSSR: true }
    })
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@resources': path.resolve('resources'),
                '{Template}': path.resolve('resources/js/Themes/default'),
                '@themeConfig': path.resolve('themeConfig.js'),
                '@core': path.resolve('resources/@core'),
                '@axios': path.resolve('resources/js/plugins/axios.js'),
                '@user-variables': path.resolve('resources/sass/variables.scss'),
                '@sass': path.resolve('resources/sass/'),
                'apexcharts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/apexcharts-clevision'),
                '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            },
        },
        plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename: "[id].css",
                linkType: false,
            }
        )],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        // enable CSS extraction
                        extractCSS: true
                    }
                }
                // ...
            ]
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        externals: [webpackNodeExternals({
            // this WILL include `jquery` and `webpack/hot/dev-server` in the bundle, as well as `lodash/*`
            allowlist: [/^vuetify/, /^lodash/, 'vue-tel-input-vuetify/lib', /^vue-tel-input-vuetify^/, /^apexcharts^/, /^vue-apexcharts/, /apexcharts/, /apexcharts-clevision/, /^apexcharts-clevision/, /^apexcharts-clevision^/, /^vue-country-flag/, /\.css$/]
        })],
    })
```

**ssr.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {createRenderer} from 'vue-server-renderer'
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import createServer from '@inertiajs/server'
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';
import store from './store'
import './plugins/acl'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import Layout from '@/Layouts/AdminLayout.vue'
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue"
import UserLayout from "@/Layouts/UserLayout.vue"
import ClientOnly from 'vue-client-only'

const moment = require('moment');


createServer((page) => createInertiaApp({
    page,
    render: createRenderer().renderToString,
    // resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    resolve: (name) => {
        // const page = (await import(`./Pages/${name}`)).default
        const page = require(`./Pages/${name}`);
        if (page.layout === undefined && name.startsWith('Admin/')) {
            page.layout = Layout
        }
        if (page.layout === undefined && name.startsWith('Dashboard/')) {
            page.layout = Layout
        }
        if (page.layout === undefined && name.startsWith('UserDashboard/')) {
            page.layout = UserLayout
        }
        if (page.layout === undefined && !name.startsWith('Admin/') && !name.startsWith('Dashboard/')) {
            page.layout = AppLayout
        }

        return page
    },
    setup({app, props, plugin}) {
        Vue.use(plugin);
        Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);
        Vue.use(PortalVue);
        Vue.component('client-only', ClientOnly)

        Vue.use(VueMeta, {
            // optional pluginOptions
            refreshOnceOnNavigation: true
        })

        Vue.mixin({methods: {route}});

        return new Vue({
            vuetify: vuetify,
            store,
            render: h => h(app, props),
        })
    },
}))
```

---

```
npx mix --mix-config=webpack.ssr.mix.js
result : webpack compiled successfully
```

**node public/js/ssr.js**

> error :
> var style = document.createElement('style');
> ^
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
> at insertStyleElement (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:44989:15)
> at addStyle (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:45104:13)
> at modulesToDom (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:44977:18)
> at module.exports (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:45135:25)
> at Module../resources/sass/overrides.scss (C:\laragon\www\gooreo2\public\js\ssr.js:41942:145)
> at **webpack_require** (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:130966:42)
> at Module../resources/js/plugins/vuetify/default-preset/preset/index.js
> (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:38073:1)
> at **webpack_require** (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:130966:42)
> at Module../resources/js/plugins/vuetify/index.js (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:38099:80)
> at **webpack_require**
> (C:\laragon\www\test2\public\js\ssr.js:130966:42)

**public/js/ssr.js**

[image]

Comment: Seeing this as well on a fresh Laravel 9 + Jetstream project after following the InertiaJS documentation on enabling SSR.

Comment: Having this problem too, did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet, the cause of the problem was vuetify so when I uninstall it it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it is by adding one line to your `webpack.mix.js` to opt in to using the `vue-style-loader`

```
mix
.js('resources/js/ssr.js', 'public/js')
.vue({
    version: 3,
    useVueStyleLoader: true // This should fix it! 
});
```

Ref: https://aaronfrancis.com/2021/vue-referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-at-insertstyleelement